# How to prove the space of integers,by using the arithmetic progressions as a basis is normal?

Tags: general-topology

If we introduce a topology into the space of integers S,by using the arithmetic progressions(from$-\infty$ to +$\infty$)as a basis.How to prove that S may be shown to be normal and metrizable?

Comment: What did you manage to prove? Which theorems can be helpful? Where did you stuck?

Comment: I didn't think S can satisfy the T4 at the beginning,but i know my countexample is wrong,and I wanted to use the definition of T4 to prove it,but this way isn't accessible.

Comment: Do you know it's T3?

Comment: Sorry,I don't know.I wanted to use T4 deduce T3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote

- $P(a,k) = \{a+kn:n\in\Bbb Z\} = \{b:k|b-a\}$,
- $\mathscr B = \{P(a,k):a,k\in\Bbb Z\}$ (this is a basis),
- $\mathscr T$ is a topology generated by $\mathscr B$.

We would like to investigate the space $(\Bbb Z,\mathscr T)$.

1. T2: If $a\neq b$ then $a\in P(a,2(b-a))$, $b\in P(b,2(b-a))$ and $P(a,2(b-a))\cap P(b,2(b-a))=\emptyset$.
2. Each $P(a,k)$ is open (of course) and closed. This is because $\Bbb Z$ can be presented as a sum
   $$ \Bbb Z = \bigcup_{i=0}^{k-1} P(a+i,k).$$
3. To prove regularity we consider $a\in P(a,k)$ and we have to prove the existence of $U\in\mathscr T$ such that $a\in U\in \bar U\subset P(a,k)$. From 2. we conclude that $U=P(a,k)$ is good.
4. $(\Bbb Z,\mathscr T)$ is 2nd countable space.
5. From Urysohn metrization theorem we get that it's metrizable.

**Another approach** (exact formula for metric)

Denote

- $l(k)=\mathbb{lcm}(1,2,3,\ldots,|k|)$ and let $Q(a,k)=P(a,l(k))$,
- $\mathscr B' = \{Q(a,k):a,k\in\Bbb Z\}$,
- $D(a,b) = (\max\{k:l(k)|b-a\})^{-1}$ for $a\neq b$ and $D(a,a)=0$.

Since $D(a,c)\leq\max\{d(a,b),d(b,c)\}$ then $D$ is a metric. Let's calculate $B(a,r)$.

$$B(a,r) = \{b: (D(a,b))^{-1}>r^{-1}\} = \{b: \max\{k:l(k)|b-a\}>r^{-1}\} = 
\{b: l(k)|b-a\text{ for some }k>r^{-1}\} = Q(a,k_r),
$$
where $k_r$ is the smallest natural number strictly greater than $r^{-1}$.

To prove that $\mathscr T_D$ - the topology generated by $D$ - coincide with $\mathscr T$, lets compare the families $\mathscr B'$ and $\mathscr B$.

Of course $\mathscr B'\subset \mathscr B$. On the other hand for any $P(a,k)$ we have
$$ P(a,k) = \bigcup_{b\in P(a,k)} Q(b,k).$$
Therefore $\mathscr T_D=\mathscr T$.

Comment: Thank u very much!I also used Lindelof Theorem(T3+C2 to T4) to prove it just now!And I I really appreciate your advice!

Comment: The question is interesting, I decided to investigate more I managed to find a formula for the metric. Please take a look at it and check if everything is correct.

Comment: Thank U!The question is from<Harry Furstenberg.On the Infinitude of Primes[J].American Mathematical Monthly.1955.62:353.>.And it is also the first problem in<Proofs from THE BOOK>